# Matlab, randomly generated value is always the same

Tags: matlab, function, random

In a MATLAB program I want to define a function who returns a randomly generated value from a Gaussian distribution with mean = 1 and variance = 0.2.
My function so far is simply:

```
     function R = r(t)
     rng shuffle;
     R = 1+0.2.*randn(1)+0.*t;
```

Sadly, if I execute the following code

```
    x=0:0.001:1; plot(x,r(x));
```

it will return me a straight line in the interval [0,1] instead of a completely random "piecewise" function. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
R = 1+0.2.*randn(1)+0.*t;
```

you generate only *one* random number (`randn(1)...`), and replicate it all through the size of `t` (`...+0.*t`).

You should change it to

```
R = 1+0.2.*randn(size(t));
```

That will give an array of independent random values with the same size as `t`.

Comment: It works, thank you. Why does my definition of 'R' doesn't work?

Comment: @user3103071: Try reading this answer again, it already explains it.

Comment: @user3103071 See my answer. You generate just one random value, and simply replicate it according to the size of `t`